# Replace part of html text with input val JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to replace part of the header with the input from the text field. When a user enters zip code the text would read "GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN 12345".

```
<h4>GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN YOUR AREA. <span id="zipPrint"></span></h4>


function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("zipNumber");
    var text = " ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        $('#hide-me').hide();
        text += .replace("YOUR AREA", x.elements[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("zipPrint").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact issue you're having? Are you getting any error messages? How do you call your function? Where's the element with the ID `zipNumber`? Please be sure to include a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Jeff is this your complete code snippet? what is the `hide-me` node? and it seems like you are missing something before `.replace`.

Comment: sorry about adding the hide-me part.

Comment: i was trying to hide the part of the string once the user enters the zip code and replace "your area" with the zip code.

Comment: You can wrap the YOUR AREA text in the span so it can be easily targeted and replace. E.g. `<span id="zipPrint">YOUR AREA</span>`

Comment: Hey j08691! This worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `text +=` line looks wrong to me. I think you need this instead.

```
var text = "GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN YOUR AREA.";
text = text.replace("YOUR AREA", x.elements[i].value);
```

That way, `"YOUR AREA"` gets replaced by the location number, and that result gets assigned to the variable `text`.

Comment: so if i use var text = "GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN YOUR AREA."; how do i display this var in my html h4 tag if the input isn't filled out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the span you set yourself up for. No need to use replace. Here I added an event listener on the input (which you can change if needed) that will replace the span in the text when you click out of the input.

```js
document.getElementById("zipNumber").addEventListener("change",myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    let zip = this.value;
    // do some zip validation if needed
    document.getElementById("zipPrint").innerHTML = zip;
}
```

```html
<h4>GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN <span id="zipPrint">YOUR AREA</span></h4>

<input id="zipNumber"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make manipulating the `DOM` simpler for us, here's how the `h4` tag will look like:

```html
<h4>GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN <span id="zipPrint">YOUR AREA.</span></h4>
```

Now the `span` tag that will display the zip code contains the text "YOUR AREA." that will be replaced by the zip code.

```js
var zipNum = document.getElementById("zipNumber"), zipPr = document.getElementById("zipPrint");
zipNum.addEventListener('blur', function myFunction() {
   var zc = this.value.trim();
   zipPr.textContent = (zc.length && !isNaN(zc)) ? zc:'YOUR AREA.';
});
```

```html
<h4>GREAT NEWS! WE HAVE A LOCATION IN <span id="zipPrint">YOUR AREA.</span></h4>
<input id="zipNumber"/>
```

**Explanations:**

A `blur` event listener is attached to the `input` tag with `id="zipNumber"` that handles the process of writing the zip code in the `h4` tag.

The anonymous function that handles the event checks if the `input` has a valid number in it: if so, the value of the `input` is placed in the `span` tag, else, if the value of the `input` is empty or doesn't represent a valid number, the string `"YOUR AREA."` is placed in the `span` tag.

Hope I pushed you further.